# Ollydbg - bytes in memory different than on disk

Tags: disassembly

I have been analyzing an application and I'm getting confused about something.
When I open an executable with OllyDbg, it shows `0xAA` byte.

[image: AA]

The same executable opened with CFF explorer at the same location… shows `0x62` instead of `0xAA`.

[image: 62]

My question is.. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.... It was ASLR issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't post comments, but perhaps you might want to mark your answer as a correct one with  V sign under the answer, so that  the question disappears from unanswered questions queue?

That will help to keep the site maintained...